# Stop INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I use MariaDB galera cluster 10.0.31 with 3 nodes.

In one node when I tail -f err log to monitor server, Every 20 seconds MySQL dumping Show InnoDB Status to err log, and the log are getting bigger.

I don't know Which variable cause to dump output Innodb status to Err log file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable you're looking for is `innodb_status_output`.  Setting it to `OFF` should stop the innodb status from being dumped into the error log.

Comment: Thank you. I think in certain conditions Galera Cluster Enable this variable automatically but I don't sure

Comment: InnoDB status will be automatically dumped to the logs in some conditions, for example when you have abnormal locks.